# Any advantage to rejecting a (cell phone) call vs ignoring it?

Tags: smartphone, information-gathering

I get several calls a month from numbers that are not on my contact list.  When I search these numbers on Google, it is not unusual see message boards saying that the number belongs to a known scammer or something along those lines. I am of the mindset that if it is someone really trying to reach me they will leave a message and I can call them back later.

[This article](http://www.npr.org/sections/alltechconsidered/2015/08/24/434313813/why-phone-fraud-starts-with-a-silent-call) states that answering these calls can lead to fraudsters creating a list of "known numbers" for future use, which could lead to more of these calls which I certainly don't want!.

My question is this:  Is it more secure to let the phone go to voicemail (no interaction required), or to reject the call (human interaction required to push the "reject call" button)?  In other words, could my pushing the "reject call" button somehow tell the "computer system" (from the previously mentioned article) on the other end there was human interaction and therefore record the number?

Are there other advantages to these options that I (most likely) missed?

Comment: I used to have a crazy ex that called and then did not talk. Once or twice she called when I was sleeping

Comment: add the number to blacklist, so no more harassment

Comment: Depending on your country, you can report those spammers to the government if the service is available (Example for France : http://www.33700.fr/).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Letting it ring has no such benefit, because either way, the caller still knows it's an active phone number by the presence of a voicemail system. (even if you haven't 'set up' your voicemail)

Unused active lines would be rather rare, because they cost money. :-)

So any time you like, just reject the call to stop that annoying ring, and proceed to enjoy your day.

Comment: Wait... I've wanted to answer the calls because I'm constantly lonely, but I don't because I don't want robots. Does that mean I can start picking up?

Comment: @ScriptKitty - one word: Twilio